# Talend- Using authorization in Trest componenet using Jersey.Core.Util.Base64

Tags: talend

I am trying to use the trest component to access the APIs which has parameters and uses the basic authorization. Looking through online, It seems that I can use Tjava and use the Jesery.core.Util.Base64 library. However, It doesn't seem to be working

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

/*String pair = "testuser:test246";

byte[] encodedBytes =  Base64.encode(pair.getBytes());

globalMap.put("authorization", new String(encodedBytes));

System.out.println(globalMap.get("authorization")); */
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Can anyone help or tell me where I can download the Jar File from and outline the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are asking about passing authorization in tRest component your code seem to be working fine.

This is my configuarion of tRest component and with your code added it is passing the authorization.

[image: job in talend]

Just remeber, in tJava import library in advanced settings.